# Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to int (in explore_fragment)

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

Showing error on getValue(User.class) in explore_fragment.
My explore_fragment is:

```
public class exploreFragment extends Fragment {
    FragmentExploreBinding binding;
    ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<>();
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    FirebaseDatabase database;

    public exploreFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        database= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding= FragmentExploreBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        UserAdapter adapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(),list);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        binding.usersRV.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        binding.usersRV.setAdapter(adapter);

        database.getReference().child("Users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                list.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    user.setUserID(dataSnapshot.getKey());

                    if(!dataSnapshot.getKey().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())){
                        list.add(user);
                    }
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        return binding.getRoot();
    }
}
```

User_model is:

```
public class User {
    private String name, profession,email,password,cname;
    private String profile;
    private String userReff;
    private int guidedCount;
    private String userID;
    private  String coverPhoto;

    public User() {
    }

    public int getGuidedCount() {
        return guidedCount;
    }
    public void setGuidedCount(int guidedCount) {
        this.guidedCount = guidedCount;
    }

    public String getCoverPhoto() {
        return coverPhoto;
    }
    public void setCoverPhoto(String coverPhoto) {
        this.coverPhoto = coverPhoto;
    }

    public User(String name, String profession, String email, String password, String cname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.profession = profession;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.cname = cname;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getProfession() {
        return profession;
    }
    public void setProfession(String profession) {
        this.profession = profession;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getCname() {
        return cname;
    }
    public void setCname(String cname) {
        this.cname = cname;
    }

    public String getProfile() {
        return profile;
    }
    public void setProfile(String profile) {
        this.profile = profile;
    }

    public String getUserReff() {
        return userReff;
    }
    public void setUserReff(String userReff) {
        this.userReff = userReff;
    }


    public String getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }
}
```

User_adapter is:

```
public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.viewHolder>{
    Context context;
    ArrayList<User> list;

    public UserAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.user_sample,parent,false);
        return new viewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewHolder holder, int position) {
        User user = list.get(position);
        Picasso.get().load(user.getProfile()).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(holder.binding.profileImage);
        holder.binding.name.setText(user.getName());
        holder.binding.profession.setText(user.getProfession());

        holder.binding.viewprofilebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){

                String visiter = list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getUserID();
                Intent intent= new Intent(context, VActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("usersid",visiter).toString();
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        UserSampleBinding binding;
        public viewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            binding = UserSampleBinding.bind(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

Error i am getting is:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.guided_app, PID: 2744
> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to int
> at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertInteger(CustomClassMapper.java:364)
> at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToPrimitive(CustomClassMapper.java:290)
> at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:215)
> at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(CustomClassMapper.java:179)
> at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$100(CustomClassMapper.java:48)
> at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:593)
> at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:563)
> at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:433)
> at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:232)
> at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:80)
> at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:203)
> at com.example.guided_app.fragment.exploreFragment$1.onDataChange(exploreFragment.java:60)
> at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
> at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
> at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

The firebase database is:

```
 "Users": {
    "59fLuGGNugPcgp6b725cFnKIzKC2": {
      "cname": "LIT",
      "email": "Stephen@gmail.com",
      "guidedCount": 0,
      "name": "Stephen Wade",
      "password": "123456",
      "profession": "Developer @ Adobe"
    },
    "7kpNGqcHeBfNqf8GrVK2Hpew0L62": {
      "cname": "BIT",
      "email": "anshul@gmail.com",
      "guided": {
        "FOQEVbKRpNYjfzAJCp1XQtnvRlh2": {
          "guidedAt": 1670152487063,
          "guidedBy": "FOQEVbKRpNYjfzAJCp1XQtnvRlh2"
        },
        "y3pV1GhdLqOnteMO64U2F4o8mMu2": {
          "guidedAt": 1670151228825,
          "guidedBy": "y3pV1GhdLqOnteMO64U2F4o8mMu2"
        }
      },
      "guidedCount": 2,
      "name": "Anshul Lanjewar",
      "password": "123456",
      "profession": "SDE @ Google"
    },
    "FOQEVbKRpNYjfzAJCp1XQtnvRlh2": {
      "cname": "SIT",
      "email": "Tanvi@gmail.com",
      "guidedCount": 0,
      "name": "Tanvi Colson",
      "password": "123456",
      "profession": "Analyst @ Google"
    },
    "Jj2RH3iopgdLU6AC3VKeeaMKAXx1": {
      "cname": "PIT",
      "email": "Shana@gmail.com",
      "guidedCount": 0,
      "name": "Shana Sharma",
      "password": "123456",
      "profession": "FullStack @ Netflix"
    },
    "gAzcrP1IYmQI0ht4qfH9WGt9U7F2": {
      "cname": "MIT",
      "email": "John@gmail.com",
      "guided": {
        "7kpNGqcHeBfNqf8GrVK2Hpew0L62": {
          "guidedAt": 1670614050015,
          "guidedBy": "7kpNGqcHeBfNqf8GrVK2Hpew0L62"
        }
      },
      "guidedCount": "gAzcrP1IYmQI0ht4qfH9WGt9U7F2",
      "name": "John Adams",
      "password": "123456",
      "profession": "Developer @ Apple"
    },
    "y3pV1GhdLqOnteMO64U2F4o8mMu2": {
      "cname": "BIT",
      "email": "kumar@gmail.com",
      "guided": {
        "7kpNGqcHeBfNqf8GrVK2Hpew0L62": {
          "guidedAt": 1670154254299,
          "guidedBy": "7kpNGqcHeBfNqf8GrVK2Hpew0L62"
        }
      },
      "guidedCount": 1,
      "name": "Kumar Mishra",
      "password": "123456",
      "profession": "SDE @ Microsoft"
    }
  }
```

I recently started with android development, so was just stucked.
I want to create an explore_fragment in which list of users is added in recyclerView and with view_profile button we can view user profile.

Comment: what value does the String have? On what line are you trying to convert it?

Comment: User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class); In this line as error on line 60 (at com.example.guided_app.fragment.exploreFragment$1.onDataChange(exploreFragment.java:60))

Comment: so, check that line of code. It's not like we know what line that is

Comment: Error for getValue

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: Are you sure all users have a `guidedCount` field of type int and not String?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes for all users

Comment: How many users exist under `Users` node?

Comment: @AlexMamo 6 users. All have the same datatype as above user.

Comment: Is it possible that this `DatabaseException` can be thrown from other parts of your code?

Comment: @AlexMamo User adapter has an intent to another activity (named VActivity), is it possible that it can have error? (Vactivity is for visit activity, its use is when user go to explore and want to view profile)

Comment: You have to check that yourself.

Comment: @AlexMamo Well i checked for that but its showing error in this line  User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);  App crashes when i go to this explore fragment

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot will all of those 6 users?

Comment: @AlexMamo Updated database of users please check

Comment: I git it. I'll provide an answer right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As expected, the following error:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to int

Arrives due to the fact that an int-type field holds a value of type String. So when deserializing, the `guidedCount` field is expected to hold a value of type int and not String, hence the error. The node that is responsible for the Exception is:

```
"guidedCount": "gAzcrP1IYmQI0ht4qfH9WGt9U7F2",
```

See, it holds a UID rather than a number. So to solve this, change that UID with a number.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was stuck in this for a long time you really helped me... Appreciated